# Get User Contacts using alexa-sdk

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-sdk-nodejs

I am building an alexa skill which sends sms for alexa-user. (Ofcourse there is business logic behind when to send these messages). And I have two hurdles in the process:-

1. Alexa can send sms to anybody from users device, is that feature exposed to someone who is building a skill using alexa-sdk?
2. Even If I use twillio, I do not want user to literally tell me the number he wants to send SMS, for that I need user contact and phone numbers (so that he just says send sms to xyz). Is there anyway to do that?

I can elaborate question, if you are not able to figure out something, just comment over it or come to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/168859/alexa-sdk).